# Bootstrap Prioritize Vertical Stacking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to ask if this kind of column stacking is possible on Bootstrap without using Javascript or JQuery.

[This One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKTk.jpg)
instead of [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhu06.jpg).

I used

> col-md-6

to style my columns at the moment, however I cannot figure out how to prioritize the stacking to fill vertical space first until it reaches the end (height) of the parent <div> followed by filling the neighboring horizontal space going down, and so on.

I could not find any topics about this anywhere in Google. So, I came here to see if it is actually possible or it isn't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But you need two wrappers. One for `1 ~ 4` second for `5` and `6`.

*jQuery is only used to demonstrate view-port change*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.wrapper').toggleClass('v2')
  });
});
```

```css
div div div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
}
.w-1,
.w-2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.v2 .w-1,
.v2 .w-2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="w-1">
    <div class="col-xs-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-2">
    <div class="col-xs-6">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>Only for demo:
<button>Toggle layout</button>
```

Comment: Am I correct to say this is not using the window height as boundary? You have to specify where you break the vertical row.

Comment: Thanks, but what I really need is only one wrapper. That way when the wrapper height changes (let's say it's using a percentage height), the floating contents will slide to the right horizontal space but the arrangement is still the same (stacking vertically downwards).